# Placing icon on top of text in MaterialButton

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I wanted to put the icon on top of the materialButton like shown here: [image]

But I couldn't find any properties in MaterialButton to set the gravity of the app:icon to top.
I could only able to set it to start or end.
Is there any way to set the create a similar button without using Vertical LinearLayout with ImageView and TextView?

Comment: in this context to what you are specifying as MaterialButton? And actually and which is the icon?

Comment: Call button, website button, save button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **`iconGravity="textTop"`**.

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        app:iconGravity="textTop" />
```

[image]

**Note:** It requires at least the version **`1.3.0-alpha02`**.

Comment: AAPT: error: 'top' is incompatible with attribute iconGravity (attr) flags [end=3, start=1, textEnd=4, textStart=2] [weak].

Comment: @Mohammad7G Are you using the version 1.3.0? Here the 1.3.0-rc01 and the value exist: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.3.0-rc01/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/values/attrs.xml#L66

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `android:drawableTop`  attribute for this

> Note : This is not only restricted for the MaterialButton you can use
> it on TextViews and other views also

Example Code :

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/app_name"  <!-- Your Text -->
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" <!-- Your Icon -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: It works but using the `compoundDrawables` (eg. `android:drawableTop`) **!=** using `iconGravity`.